# Was Guinan affected by lack of REM sleep?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "[Night Terrors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Terrors_(episode))," everyone except Data is slowly degenerating, due to a lack of REM sleep caused by alien transmissions within Tyken's Rift.

In one scene, Guinan fires a weapon at the ceiling of Ten Forward in order to try and stop a fight.

I wonder if this action by Guinan was partially caused by her mind being weakened. This sort of behavior doesn't seem particularly consistent with Guinan's character. It is true that she called security first, but if this were a normal day and a fight broke out, I find it hard to believe that she'd fire a weapon at the ceiling.

On the other hand, it's quite possible that El-Aurians need no REM sleep, or much less REM sleep than other humanoids, to function properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Guinan **was** affected. The line below appears in the [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/191.txt)

> **Guinan:** (adjusts the setting) *... anybody want to see number two?*
>
> The group is at a dead halt, staring at her
>
> **GUINAN:** ***I'm not feeling so good myself... in fact, I'm real irritable... so I hope nobody's got the idea they're going through this door. Because they'll have to go through me first.***
>
> Gillespie and the others glare at her. But they don't move.

In the [actual episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/191.htm), the line was removed, presumably because it's superfluous to the plotline.

Comment: Bah. I would have loved to have seen Whoopi deliver that.

Comment: "*Michael Piller [noted](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Night_Terrors_(episode)) that the pace of the show was so slow that the episode ran nine minutes over and had to be severely cut."*. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Her firing the gun is playing more upon the trope of a bartender stashing a gun behind the counter to protect themselves or break up fights.

From TV Tropes: ["Two Shots from Behind the Bar"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwoShotsFromBehindTheBar)

> The bartender quickly dives behind the bar... but then he emerges, shotgun in tow and ready to quell any disturbances to his business.

In fact, this scene is listed as an example of the trope

I don't know that we know enough of El Aurian culture / biophysics to make any other determination